# My app is rejected because of metadata

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my app on iTune Connect , but it had been rejected because of the metadata. My app use Username and Password to login. And I dont provide demo Username and Password in metadata.

Ao apple had rejected my app and ask for demo Username and Password. That is fine, but my question is. I had clicked (by mistake) submit metadata button on iTune Connect without updating metadata, and now my app is once more `waiting for review` state. And I dont see any where that how can I resubmit my metadata.

So do I have to wait for some time so apple once more reject my app and I can resubmit metadata or I can resubmit metadata by some other way. And yes, I have sended mail to apple about this problem. And waiting for their answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes you can resubmit the meta data. You can edit your current meta data.
2. Don't wait for apple to reject your app.
3. In itunes connect there's section "Review Notes (Optional)" Put your demo username and password there. And resubmit the app.
4. If you wait for apple to reject the app then you'll loose at least 7 more days.
5. Just go ahead and submit the metadata again.